# How wrap dynamically created image element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angular6

I want display image preview on change event of file input. So I am creating Image element using JavaScript and I want to wrap it inside a div to display a close button. To achieve this I have written following code:

```
preview(event, imageList) {
    let imgLen = event.target.files.length;
    if (imgLen > 0) {
        for (let i = 0; i < imgLen; i++) {
            let myImage = new Image(100, 100);
            myImage.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[i]);
            myImage.setAttribute('style', 'margin: 5px');
            imageList.appendChild("<div>" + myImage + "</div>");
        }
    }
}
```

But I throwing error at the run time.
error [image]

Comment: Just adding: You don't need the `if (imgLen > 0)` condition since for loop will not even run if  `imgLen < 1` and will bail out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
var divNode = document.createElement('DIV');
divNode.appendChild(myImage);
imageList.appendChild(divNode);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
preview(event, imageList) {
    let imgLen =event.target.files.length;
    if(imgLen > 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i< imgLen; i++) {
        let myImage = new Image(100, 100);
        myImage.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[i]);
        let div = document.createElement('div');
        div.appendChild(myImage);
        myImage.setAttribute('style', 'margin: 5px'); 
        imageList.append( myImage);    
      }  
    }
```